# Review block not displayed on product page

Tags: magento-1.7, product, review

I am using a custom theme-celebrity by athlete  and now the problem is the review block from the product page is missing. When i click on "Be first to review this product" ,it leads to another page with url/#review-form but this page also does nto have review form.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

You need to edit `app/design/frontend/default/YourTheme/layout/catalog.xml` file and find `catalog_product_view tag`, Inside this reference add the following code:

```
<block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.info.product_additional_data" as="product_review" template="review/product/view/list.phtml">
<block type="review/form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form"/></block>
```

Now edit `app/design/frontend/default/YourTheme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml` file and add following code on appropriate place:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_review') ?>
```